Confusion of vanishing of motivic (co)homology
I'm trying to understand a vanishing result in Haesemeyer-Weibel as follows:
Lemma $1.33$ For all smooth $X$ and $p > q$, we should have $Hom_{DM}(R, R_{tr}(X)(q)[p])=0$.
From my understanding, the proof seems like trying to say that the chain complex of sheaves $R_{tr}(Y)(q)[p]$ vanish below homological degree $p-q$, and this group is just the homology at the zero-position, which implies it must be $0$.
But the thing I don't understand is that should not we take the hyperhomology of this chain complex? Also, in the case of motivic cohomology, I think we have$$H^{p,q}(X,R) \cong Hom_{DM}(R_{tr}(X), R(q)[p]) \cong Hom_{DM}(R_{tr}(X)(-q)[-p], R)$$ and if we follow the logic above, we would have the motivic cohomology vanish when $p<q$, which does not seem correct. Does it mean $R_{tr}(X)(q)$ is a cofibrant object but not fibrant?

Please add a definition to https://math.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/1387 for the tag [tag:stable-homotopy-theory] if you want. Thanks
